# How do I design a 2D stadium section view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to design a stadium section view that is later supposed to be able to have a hover effect that highlights different sections on the stadium map when a user hovers over one of the sections. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to create such a design and could help me. It should work similarly to the ticketing marketplace FanPass but a lot more simpler, where you can only choose sections of the stadium but not seats. Even if you know an article on something similar or know something that could help me get just get started is much appreciated since I can’t find anything on this.
Thanks in advance :)

I tried searching for the exact problem and also searched for how interactive photos work and couldn’t find anything that would work

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site! Unfortunately, your question doesn't fit our format very well. This this will likely get closed as needing focus, since it generally describes a very broad problem. If you have specific code that you are having trouble with that we can definitively answer, then come back and get answers to those questions then. In the meantime though, some things you may want to learn are [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) and [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)